# Node.js Logging to File deleting old log on restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I have a Node.js Application that I execute with `systemctl start app.service` on my server.
I configured my package.json correctly that on app start the log is being written in app.log with
`node app.js > app.log 2>&1` the problem is now that with every restart the old log is being deleted and a new one is genereted. I want to keep my old log data for debugging purposes. How can I edit the log statement that the old log will be saved or the new log just appended? Is this possible?

I already searched in Stackoverflow and Google for a solution but did not find one. I was expecting to keep my old logs.

Comment: What are you using to write the logs to the file? Could you post some code so that we can help you better?

Comment: I am using the standard node.js functionality "node app.js > app.log 2>&1" to redirect console.log() statements to a log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using IO redirection, if you want to append to a file rather than overwrite the file, you need to use ">>" instead of ">". For example:

```
node app.js >> app.log
```